# prefix namespace is removed

Tags: php, xml

I want to export some invoice information into an xml file.
This is how it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:stat="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DocumentStatusCode-1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Invoice/>');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns', 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:qdt', 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:cbc', 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:udt', 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:cac', 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:ccts', 'urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:udt', 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:stat', 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DocumentStatusCode-1.0');


    $xml->addChild('cbc:UBLVersionID', '2.1'); ?>
```

But when I run the php code, the prefixes are not there anymore. How can I solve this?

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" stat="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DocumentStatusCode-1.0">
<UBLVersionID>2.1</UBLVersionID>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the namespace as the third argument:

```
$xml->addAttribute('qdt',
    'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2',
    'xmlns');

// some lines omitted...

$xml->addChild('UBLVersionID', '2.1', 'cbc');
```

Comment: this gives me:`<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
<UBLVersionID xmlns="cbc">2.1</UBLVersionID>
<ID xmlns="cbc">2015000003</ID>
</Invoice>`
no colons and also the attributes of the xml variable are gone..

Answer (score -1):

You don't add the attribute itself to the right namespace.

The `xmlns` attribute defines the default namespace. The attribute itself is in no namespace.

All `xmlns:*` attributes are the other namespace definitions. They use the  reserved namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`.

So if invoice is part of the default namespace you should move that definition into the template XML.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"/>'
);
$xml->addAttribute(
  'xmlns:qdt',      
  'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2',
  'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/'
);

echo $xml->asXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"/>
```

But you don't need to add the namespace attributes manually, if you add elements to the namespaces, the definition will be added as needed:

```
$xmlns = [
  'cbc' => 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2'
];
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"/>'
);

$xml->addChild('cbc:UBLVersionID', '2.1', $xmlns['cbc']);

echo $xml->asXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
</Invoice>
```

Adding the attributes manually can avoid multiple definitions of the same namespace in siblings. But it is an optimization only.

Comment: I get this:
`<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
<UBLVersionID xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2.1</UBLVersionID>
<ID xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2015000003</ID>
</Invoice>` not really what I want..